# Difference modes of convergence of a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $(r_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence in $(0,1]$, $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables such that: $P(X_n=0) = 1 - r_n, P(X_n = \frac{1}{r_n}) = r_n$. Show that:

1. $X_n \to 0$ in probability iff $r_n \to 0$.
2. $X_n \to 0$ a.s iff $\sum\limits_{n \geq 1} r_n < \infty$.

1) Is my work correct?

$\Leftarrow$: If $r_n \to 0$, then $P(X_n = 0) \to 1 \Rightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0, P(X_n \leq \epsilon) \to 1$, which means $X_n \to 0$ in probability.

$\Rightarrow$: If $X_n \to 0$ in probability, then $P(X_n \leq 1/2) \to 1$. This means $P(X_n = 0) = 1-r_n \to 1$ (as $1/r_n \geq 1 > 1/2$). Thus $r_n \to 0$.

2) I think Borel-Cantelli lemma can be useful, but I don't know how to apply it here. Could anyone give me a hint?